# How to select a condition to occur once in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that creates a df with the row values according to a set of conditions. One out of three conditions are randomly selected in each iteration of the loop. How do I change my code so that condition 3 is selected x times, and that condition 1 and 2 are randomly selected for the remaining times? The number of times the outer for loop is iterated is defined by num_groups

```
num_rows = 3
num_cols = 4
num_groups = 2
dfs = []

for group in range(num_groups): # number of groups
    # Create an empty DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Randomly determine the condition for each row
    conditions = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=num_rows)

    # Iterate over rows
    for condition in conditions:
        # Create row data based on the condition
        if condition == 1:
            row_data = ['X'] * (num_cols // 2) + ['-'] * (num_cols // 2)
        elif condition == 2:
            row_data = ['-'] * (num_cols // 2) + ['X'] * (num_cols // 2)
        elif condition == 3:
            row_data = ['X'] * num_cols


        # Create a temporary DataFrame for the current row
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_data])

        # Concatenate the temporary DataFrame to the main DataFrame
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

    # Append the current DataFrame to the list
    dfs.append(df)


# Concatenate the list of DataFrames into a final DataFrame
out = pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(len(dfs)))
out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([out.index.get_level_values(0),
                                       range(len(out))])

out = out.stack().unstack([0, -1], fill_value='.')
out = out.set_axis(range(out.shape[1]), axis=1)

out
```

Comment: Is that condition 3 selected x times, followed by random 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes exactly. The number of rows in out should be num_groups*num_rows.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a distribution list where you store how many times a given condition is expected to be met. In the case where the third condition must be drawn x times (4 in the below example), and the other conditions are evenly distributed, we would have the following distribution:

```py
total_number_of_times = num_groups * num_rows
x_times_condition = 4
distributions_conditions = [3] * x_times_condition + [1, 2] * ((total_number_of_times - x_times_condition) // 2)
random.shuffle(distributions_conditions)
# example: [3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2]
```

Notice that the remaining amount of conditions `(total_number_of_times - x_times_condition) // 2` should be a whole number.

Then we simply need to split the distribution array into groups, adapting your code, we have:

```py
for group in range(num_groups): # number of groups
    # Create an empty DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Randomly determine the condition for each row
    conditions = distributions_conditions[group*num_rows:(group + 1)*num_rows] # <--- single change

    # Iterate over rows
    for condition in conditions:
        # Create row data based on the condition
        if condition == 1:
            row_data = ['X'] * (num_cols // 2) + ['-'] * (num_cols // 2)
        elif condition == 2:
            row_data = ['-'] * (num_cols // 2) + ['X'] * (num_cols // 2)
        elif condition == 3:
            row_data = ['X'] * num_cols


        # Create a temporary DataFrame for the current row
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_data])

        # Concatenate the temporary DataFrame to the main DataFrame
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

    # Append the current DataFrame to the list
    dfs.append(df)
```